# Should separate or new model be created for every table in Cakephp applications?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new to Cakephp and developing small web application. In my application, admin can add **event** and once even is added, if required admin can also **add one or multiple images to each event**. For this I created two tables '**events**' & '**event_images**', all events added by admin gets saved in events table (and all the images of event should get stored in events_images table).

My questions are::

1) Do I need to create an entirely new model for event images OR should I write upload event image code in events model itself ?

2) If I Should write upload event image code in events model itself(instead of creating event image model) then how to do validation for these 2 different forms (event & event_images) in same event model ?

It would be very kindful of you guys if you help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a new model for event images.

2) The easiest way to get started would just be to have two completely separate steps: 1) create an event (with validation handled by the event model), and 2) add images to that event (with validation being handled by the event_images model). That way, you don't have a single form dealing with records from multiple models.